# How to properly enhance Qt HTML5 application?

Tags: html, qt, qwebview

In Qt Creator I see "HTML5 Application" wizard. It creates a project with "html5applicationviewer" sub-project that loads the HTML and injects the object named "Qt" object with only public slot "quit" (which is used in the demo code).

If I change html5applicationviewer to also inject my object in addition to "Qt", it Qt Creator suggests to "upgrade" html5applicationviewer; and there's a comment `This file was generated ... It is recommended not to modify this file` in html5applicationviewer's files.

How to properly add more Qt C++ things to the HTML part in Qt HTML5 applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there are two ways you can extend your Qt HTML5 application. The first one is indeed by injecting your QObjects to make them visible in JavaScript. This you do in response to `javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()` signal emitted by web view page main frame.

The second way is to provide custom plugin factory to the web view page (see `QWebPage::setPluginFactory()` method). This way allows you creating Qt objects (e.g. widgets) instances directly in HTML code (using `<object>` tag).